# slow transition on hover css

Tags: css, hover, transition

I have a slider with a background that appears on hover here:
http://nigarn.com

I have tried a multitude of CSS to slow the transition of the white background but none have worked.

This is what I currently have:

```css
.sp-layer {
    opacity: 1 !important;
 -moz-transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
    transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
color: #fff;
padding-top: 157px!important;
padding-bottom: 180px!important;
 pointer-events: none;
}


.sp-slide:hover .sp-layer {
    opacity: 1 !important;
 -moz-transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
    transition: opacity 7.5s!important;
color: #000;
background:url(http://www.nigarn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/slide-background-2-5.png)no-repeat center top;
padding-top: 157px!important;
padding-bottom: 180px!important;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

But the background still pops up immediately.  If anyone has a suggestion I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are animating the `opacity` property when you are actually trying to animate the `background-image`; the `opacity` is never `0` to begin with. Secondly, there is currently no way to fade in a `background-image` via CSS `transition`.

As your background image seems to be a uniform translucent color, you should use `background-color` instead.

```
.sp-layer {
    transition: background-color 0.75s;
}
.sp-slide:hover .sp-layer {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```